# Xamarin & MVVM-Light: NullPointerException when trying to display an AlertDialog

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvm-light

I am trying to use mvvm-light in an Android application build with Xamarin, but I don't know why i can't use the DialogService implementation if IDialogService.

Here is the `MainViewModel.cs` in shared code:

```
private RelayCommand _getEventsCommand;

public RelayCommand GetEventsCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _getEventsCommand
            ?? (_getEventsCommand = new RelayCommand(() => _dialogService.ShowMessage("sample alert message", "Sample alert title")));
    }
}
```

This command is called when a button is clicked and when I tap the button I get the following exception:

```
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono    (16027): Unhandled Exception:
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono    (16027): Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono    (16027):   --- End of managed Java.Lang.NullPointerException stack trace ---
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono    (16027): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono    (16027):   at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:222)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono    (16027):   at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:452)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono    (16027):   at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native Method)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono    (16027):   at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:30)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono    (16027):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono    (16027):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono    (16027):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono    (16027):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono    (16027):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono    (16027):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono    (16027):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono    (16027):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono    (16027):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono    (16027): 
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono-rt (16027): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono-rt (16027):   --- End of managed Java.Lang.NullPointerException stack trace ---
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono-rt (16027): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono-rt (16027):   at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:222)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono-rt (16027):   at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:452)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono-rt (16027):   at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native Method)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono-rt (16027):   at mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:30)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono-rt (16027):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono-rt (16027):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono-rt (16027):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono-rt (16027):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono-rt (16027):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono-rt (16027):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono-rt (16027):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono-rt (16027):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
03-17 17:20:59.850 E/mono-rt (16027):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

By using mvvm-light, isn't it supposed to work by using just the existing DialogService implementation from the library?

Comment: Do you have a theme associated with the AlertDialog? Please check if you class is calling a context.GetTheme or context.Theme.

Comment: It is just a simple project with a view having a button on it binding to the relay command. Just this.

Comment: did you define a theme for you application. I think that is you problem by looking at the stack trace you published.

Comment: No, I didn't define any theme.

Comment: Can you provide the code you used to initialize the _dialogService?